# How to break a product of three polynomials

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, best-practices

I have

```
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8+x^{10})(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+x^{20})$$
```

but is too long to fit the page. How to break  this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Consider [accepting one of the answers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer).

Answer (score 12):

First: [Don't use `$$`/`$$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

The following fits in a book with a text width of 7 inches:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[textwidth = 7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{split}
  &(1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + x^{4} + x^{5} + x^{6})\\
  &\cdot (1 + x^{2} + x^{4} + x^{6} +x^{8} + x^{10})\\
  &\cdot (1 + x^{5} + x^{10} + x^{15} + x^{20})
\end{split}
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{split}
  \MoveEqLeft (1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + x^{4} + x^{5} + x^{6})\\
  &\cdot (1 + x^{2} + x^{4} + x^{6} +x^{8} + x^{10})\\
  &\cdot (1 + x^{5} + x^{10} + x^{15} + x^{20})
\end{split}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice the use of `\MoveEqLeft` (from the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package) in the second example, which is equivalent to `&\quad`.

Comment: Maybe adding a trailing `\cdot{}`? Or a leading one in the second and third lines.

Comment: It isn't an equation, it's a product. I use multline but I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: @JoanTarrasso Then you should have told us. Please make a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you want.

Comment: @JoanTarrasso Well how do you want it to look?  Is it a numbered equation?  is there other math in the vicinity?  Left-aligned stack, centered, or right-aligned?

Comment: It's alone and not numbered.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
The product is
\begin{multline*}
(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8+x^{10})\\
  \times(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+x^{20})
\end{multline*}
and some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the problem? It fits on a single line. (Also, please update your question instead of posting an answer.)

Comment: No, it isn't. No for a book of 7".  And I'm new and writing with a mobile phone in the countryside, I promise to learn the rules of this forum. Regards.

Comment: Once again: Tell us something like this when you post your question! It's vital to the answer(s).

Comment: OK Svend. I promise learn at home in my laptop with a better connection.

Comment: I'm going to confront Mathematics into Type  when I come back at home. Good night.

Comment: @JoanTarrasso -- "math into type" is good for general layout and formatting advice, but it's not going to give you much help translating that into latex input.  there are other sources for that information.  the `amsmath` users guide (`texdoc amsmath`) goes part of the way, but you'll need more than that.  some people recommend the [latex wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX); i'd like to reserve judgment on that, but you might find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Using a right-aligned stack.  I did it with two lines, but an extra `\\` and `\times` can be used if you prefer 3 lines.  The horizontal line show the margin extent.  The `16pt` is the distance between baselines in the math expression.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill
\setstackgap{L}{16pt}
\[\Longstack[r]{
  (1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + x^{4} + x^{5} + x^{6})
  (1 + x^{2} + x^{4} + x^{6} +x^{8} + x^{10})\qquad{}\\
  \times (1 + x^{5} + x^{10} + x^{15} + x^{20})
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I, too, thought sometihng like this was what the OP wanted but apparently it has to fit in a book with pages 7 inches wide (assuming yet another thing doesn't come up).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg My wife expects *me* to read *her* mind, too, so I'm used to such tribulation.

Answer (score 3):

You've mentioned in a comment that the page width of your document is 7", but you haven't mentioned how wide the text block is. Assuming a text block width of 4.5" (i.e., combined left- and right-hand margins of 2.5"), a font size of `10pt`, and use of the `Computer Modern` font family, TeX *can* make the entire expression fit on a single line. This is possible because the width parameter around the `+` symbols is shrinkable as well as stretchable.

If you do *not* want to make TeX apply so much shrinkage to the spacing around the `+` symbols, or if your basic font size is larger than `10pt` and hence if the entire polynomial can't fit on one line, you could use a `multline`* environment to typeset the entire expression across *three lines* in a staggered fashion. (If you don't like the `\times` symbol, consider using `\cdot` instead.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline*' environment
\usepackage[textwidth=4.5in]{geometry} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\noindent
The following line is 4.5" wide:
\hrule
\[
(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)
(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8+x^{10})
(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+x^{20})
\]
\begin{multline*}
(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)\\
\times(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8+x^{10})\\
\times(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+x^{20})
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```